# Automatically assign permissions to any file copied into directory

Tags: linux, chmod

I have a directory and I'd like for any file added to that directory to automatically have chmod performed with a specific set of permissions.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: are subfolders included?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reacting to filesystem events (in linux) can be done using [inotify](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify).

There are many tools built on inotify which allow you to call commands in reaction to file system events. One such tool is [`incron`](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=about&lang=en). You might like it since it can be configured in a way similar to the familiar `cron` daemon.

Files moved into a monitored directory generate an `IN_MOVED_TO` event.

So [the incrontab file](http://linux.die.net/man/5/incrontab) would contain an entry like

```
/path/to/watch IN_MOVED_TO /bin/chmod 0644 $#
```

Comment: Thanks, that'll definitely do the trick. It seems to me there should be a filesystem flag one can set that would allow a directory to automatically force inheritance of its permissions on any children that are moved, copied, or created in it. I guess I'll suggest that as a feature request for Ext5 ;)

Comment: We run into problems, if we don't use the complete path. Therefore I would commend to use path plus filename:

`/path/to/watch IN_MOVED_TO,IN_CLOSE_WRITE /bin/chmod 0644 $@/$#`

Answer (score 1):

You can create a cron that checks/chmods files in that directory.

Something like this will work:

```
find /path/to/directory -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 0644
```

(Of course you have to edit the path and set the permissions you need)

Answer (score 1):

The question is too unspecified and it is dangerous to give any answer as it is.

Who (/what) creates files in aforementioned directory? What rights do you want to set and why do you think this is needed? Why whatever creates them cannot put expected rights on its own?

For instance, all these "find | chmod" or inotify watchers and other tools mentioned in other comments are a huge security hole if this is a directory everyone can put files to and such a chmoding command would be run with root privs, as it can be tricked into a following a symlink and chmoding stuff like /etc/shadow.

This /can/ be implemented securely of course, but chances are the actual problem does not require any of this.

Comment: Thanks for that security-minded perspective. This is for a local system where I am the only user (barring intrusion into my private network, although this host doesn't have SSHD running so without a rootkit I think an intruder would need to gain physical access to the PC in order to exploit the inotify watcher, in which case I would have bigger problems than the intruder simply exploiting said watcher.